# How to perform security updates of Docker Alpine

Tags: security, update, alpine, cve

I stumbled upon a tricky situation: I read on the [Docker Alpine main page](https://www.alpinelinux.org/) that the image is getting updated every month for minor versions/security fixes. Packages with CVE are not updated for the stable version (v3.17.*) but are on the `edge` version.

I know that there is the possibility to update a package by specifying the release version like `apk add git --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community`. I won't do it though because `edge` is not stable.

Here is my real life situation:

Using Docker Alpine 3.17.3, the `git` package is on version [2.38.4-r1](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=git&branch=v3.17&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) (suffering from [CVE-2022-23521](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-23521)). The fixed version is [2.39.1-r0](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=git&branch=edge&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) but is on edge.

Should I simply live with the fact that my CI is complaining and wait for the fix(es) to be available on a stable release? What is the best approach?

Comment: Care to elaborate the -1 please?

Answer (score 0):

This CVE may result in remote code execution and is categorized as critical. I think that it is better to use "unstable" version than allow your service to be exposed to it. Just check if there are any known vulnerabilities on the version you want to install.

Because git is on main branch (not community), you can install edge version like this:

```
apk add git --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
```

As of today it will install  git (2.40.1-r0)

There are many other options like
building git from source with your preferred version with multistage,  use different distibution, or finding an older version of git package that doesn't contain any security issues - it will be much more tested/stable

Comment: That is one option but it is very impractical in a CI/CD environment.